# How to duplicate and EmbeddedDocument in Doctrine (with MongoDb)

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, php-mongodb

In  in Doctrine ODM 1.0beta3, I need to take an @EmbeddedDocument from a Document, and to put it in another Document.

However when I try to do this, I get strange results.

There is a way to duplicate and EmbeddedObject?

EDIT:

The "strange" result is that a property of this embedded document is inserted alongside the other embedded documents.

---

More details:

I have a `Queue` embedded document with several `Job` documents in an `@EmbedMany` relationship:

```
Queue: -> [ Job, Job, Job]
```

Also some `Job`s have another `Job` in a `@EmbedOne` property called `$callback`:

```php
class Job {
    /** @EmbedOne(targetDocument="Cron\Model\Document\Job") */
    private $callback;

    /** @Hash */
    private $result;
}

/*
 * @EmbeddedDocument 
 */
class Queue {
    /** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="Cron\Model\Document\Job") */
    private $jobs = array();

    //Getters and setters...
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the $callback Job, add a value to the $result hash and to enqueue this Job in the $jobs array().

What I get is the Job enqueued, but also the $result hash in the $jobs array, as if it was a Job document.

jobs array from mongodb:

```
...
[2] => Array
(
  [parameters] => Array
  (
    [field] => office
    [result] => "foo"
  )
)

[3] => Array
(
  [_id] => 638
  [parameters] => Array
  (
    [field] => office
    [result] => "foo"
  )
)
```

The code is this:

```php
$job = $queue->getLastJob();
$callback = $job->getCallback();
$params = $callback->getParameters();
$params['result'] = 'foo';
$callback->setParameters($params);
$queue->addJobs($callback);
```

Comment: What are the strange results?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would tackle this problem as you would in any other language.

Just copy the object:

`$some_obj["embedded_document"] = $other_obj["embedded_document"];`

My understanding is that php makes a copy of the object instead of a reference and I've confirmed it locally.

What strange results are you getting exactly? If you provide some more information I can try to help.

Cheers!